# Asp mvc 4 model binding with post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, model, model-binding

im looking for a way (if there's any) to make the model binding process to work with a List of objects, on a post method.
I can easily display the list. But when it comes to the user upload a "Bien" with a post method i cant make the framework bind each list element correctly. You can see the page part where i try to make labels and text boxes is commented, cause i keep getting exceptions, so i guess im doing it wrong and i cant find a way to upload a variable amount of parameters on my model.

This is the Model:

```
 public class BienModel
    {

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre del Bien.")]
        public String Nombre { set; get; }


        public List<Atributo> Atributos { set; get; }


    }

    public class Atributo
    {
        [Required]
        public String nombre { set; get; }

        [Required]
        public String valor { set; get; }
        public Atributo(){}
        public Atributo(String n, String v){
            this.nombre=n;
            this.valor=v;
        }


    }
```

And this is the page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {


    <fieldset>
        <legend>Publicar bien form.</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nombre)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nombre)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Nombre)
            </li>
            @*@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Atributos.Count;i++ )
            {

                @Html.Label(Model.Atributos[i].nombre)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Atributos[i].valor)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Atributos[i].valor)

            }*@

        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Publicar!" />
    </fieldset>

}
```

And this the controller

```
public ActionResult PublicarBien()
    {

        //Pido a la logica los atributos

        BienModel b = new BienModel();

        b.Atributos = new List<Atributo>();
        b.Atributos.Add(new Atributo("Atributo1", ""));
        b.Atributos.Add(new Atributo("Atributo2", ""));
        b.Atributos.Add(new Atributo("Atributo3", ""));
        b.Atributos.Add(new Atributo("Atributo4", ""));


        return View(b);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PublicarBien(BienModel b)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //se da de alta el bien

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ModelState.AddModelError("",ex.Message);
        }

        return View(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code seems fine. If the controller action you are posting to takes a `BienModel` as action parameter then binding should work fine:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(BienModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

You might also take a look at the [`following article`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) about the standard convention in ASP.NET MVC for binding to a list.

Also currently you only have an input field for the `valor` property. The `nombre` property doesn't have a corresponding input field so you will never get its value back. If you want that to happen you could use a hidden field:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Atributos.Count;i++ )
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Atributos[i].valor, Model.Atributos[i].nombre)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Atributos[i].nombre)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Atributos[i].valor)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Atributos[i].valor)
}
```

Comment: The nombre property is actually a fixed value, the user only inputs a valor property, nombre is loaded from the GET method, which then sends the model back to the view, but i keep getting null pointer exceptions.

Comment: On which line of your code are you getting those exceptions? Is it inside the POST action? Or maybe inside the view that was rendered afterwards? It's impossible to help you if you don't provide any details about the problems you are encountering.

Comment: I added the controller code. 
Exception is thrown here: @Html.Label(Model.Atributos[i].nombre) when i press the send button.

Comment: Of course that you will get this exception. Did you even read my answer? You never sent the value of the `nombre` property to your controller action because you don't have a corresponding input field. Now read my answer more carefully and pay attention to the hidden field I included to make this value being sent to the controller action: `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Atributos[i].nombre)`.

Comment: I see, that worked out with the hidden field now :)
Also, can you tell me what's the difference between "@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Atributos[i].valor, Model.Atributos[i].nombre)" and "@Html.Label(Model.Atributos[i].nombre)" ? Since i only want to show the nombre attribute